# Is Hybrid Encryption CCA secure?

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, hybrid-encryption

If Enc is a PKE(Public Key Encryption) with key generation algorithm KG and message space $M = \{0, 1\}^n$, and SE is a Symmetric Key Encryption(SKE) with key space $\{0, 1\}^n$ and message space $M' = \{0, 1\}^*$ then the hybrid encryption
uses the same key generation KG, but its message space is $M' = \{0, 1\}^*$ and its encryption procedure $Enc'(p_k, m)$ picks a random symmetric key $k \gets \{0, 1\}^n$ and outputs ciphertext $(c, c')$ where $c = Enc(p_k, k)$ and $c' = SE(k, m)$. The decryption given $(c, c')$ decrypts $k$ from $c$ using the private key corresponding to pk and then decrypts $m$ from $c'$ using $k$.

If Enc is a CPA secure PKE on $M = \{0, 1\}^n$ and SE is IND secure SKE on$ M' = \{0, 1\}^*$,  is Enc' CPA secure PKE on $M'$?

If Enc is CPA secure PKE and SE is CCA secure SKE, is Enc'
 CCA secure?

Comment: Not quite sure, but intuition tells me that Enc should be CCA secure (at least when considering active adversaries).

Comment: So "Introduction to Modern Cryptography" talks a bit about hybrid encryption and KEMs. It would appear that plain CPA-secure encryption doesn't yield a CCA-secure KEM (because eg ElGamal is CPA secure but you can win the KEM-CCA game using the homomorphism) and the book requires a CCA secure KEM for CCA secure hybrid encryption.

Answer (score 3):

If the KEM is only CPA-secure, then the resulting scheme might not be CCA-secure. For example, consider a CPA-secure KEM that ignores the last bit of its ciphertext. Then it is possible to modify a KEM ciphertext in a way that doesn't affect its payload, which is enough to break CCA security of the hybrid scheme.

If the KEM and DEM are both CCA-secure, then the overall hybrid scheme is also CCA-secure. This is proved formally in Section 7 of:

> Cramer, Shoup: [Design and Analysis of Practical Public-Key Encryption Schemes Secure against Adaptive Chosen Ciphertext Attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/108.pdf)

However, it is possible to have a CCA-secure hybrid encryption scheme where the KEM is (slightly) weaker than CCA secure. This was first demonstrated in:

> Kurosawa, Desmedt: [A New Paradigm of Hybrid Encryption Scheme](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520425/crypto-hybrid-04.pdf)

The weakened KEM security definition and composition theorem for hybrid encryption were formalized/generalized in:

> Hofheinz, Kiltz: [Secure Hybrid Encryption from Weakened Key Encapsulation](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520425/crypto-hybrid-04.pdf)